# error Only supported for TrueType fonts or cannot open resource when using wordcloud python windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, window, word-cloud

im trying to create wordcloud using this code

```
font = 'C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf' word_string = ' '.join(trigrams) wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path=font, width=800, height=800, background_color='white').generate(word_string)


plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

but got error either cannot open resource or Only supported for TrueType fonts.
im checking in

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
print([f.name for f in fm.fontManager.ttflist])
```

and some of font that im trying to use eg. Arial is installed. im so confused what i did wrong. is there any suggestion here? thankyou

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Python 3.7.10):

```
pip3 install --upgrade Pillow
pip3 install --upgrade wordcloud
```

If you are working in a Jupyter Notebook environment, make sure to restart the kernel before validating it works.